# VBA Restric method on Outlook subject does not find entire phrase

Tags: vba

I am trying to restrict Outlook items with a specific phase in the subject.  the following filter works to find items with the word "signature"

```
strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%Signature%'"
```

However, I would like to find items with the phrase: "signature due"

This filter does not find those items:

```
strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%Signature due%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below. Replaced blank space with %20. Refer the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867646.aspx)

```
strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%Signature%20due%'"
```